# No touchscreen input in App when Ubuntu launches

Tags: ubuntu, input, touch

Ubuntu 16.04 using a touchscreen. We are developing an application that will launch when the OS first starts up. We plan to use the computer with touch screen only. No mouse or keyboard.

The problem we are having is that we cannot get the touchscreen to work when the application first launches, unless the touchscreen has been "touched" before the application is launched. For example we boot up the computer, open the app, and we touch the screen but there is no response. (mouse and keyboard work fine) We quit the application, and since the touchscreen has been used at least once already, we can now reopen the app and everything works fine. Or... we boot the machine, use the touchscreen and therefore can now open the app and everything works as it should.

Because the finished product will require the computer to boot directly into the application and the standard user will not have access to either mouse or keyboard, I was hoping someone who knew more about linux input devices could point me a way to either script a touch event from a startup script or had some better solution for the problem that we are having.

Many thanks for anyone who has more knowledge on the subject.

UPDATE: Was wondering if this might be a driver issue. Is there a way to force the OS to assign a specific driver? The driver I want to use is the hid-multitouch driver and I am fairly certain it is available for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Seems that the issue could be driver related. The touch screen device we are using is not being assigned the HID multitouch driver. The manufacturer Ilitek however has two models that look to be supported  http://lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/multitouch-devices.html